# What are sideways and backwards power attack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the two-handed tree, there are perks called Sweep and Warmaster.

- Description of Sweep: sideways power attacks with two-handed weapons hit all targets in front of you.
- Description of Warmaster: backwards power attacks have a 25% chance to paralyze the target.

So, how do I perform sideways and backwards power attacks? How do I know I performed any of those two (animation, angle of swing or something else)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sideways power attacks are initiated by moving to the left or right while holding attack.

Similarly, backwards power attacks are initiated by moving backwards while holding attack.

Comment: I am stuck on this. I am using a PC. If I hold down right mouse button while doing nothing else I get a vertical power attack. If I press A or D (strafe left or right) and then press the right mouse button, my movement stops and I get again a vertical power attack. I can't seem to move *and* do a power attack, so I can't see how to do a horizontal one.

Comment: Answer: you cannot do a horizontal attack if you are sneaking. This wasn't clear from anything I had read before.